# как сделать отображение товаров списком и кирпичами

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

всем привет.
использую laravel, хочу сделать на сайте отображение товаров списком и кирпичами.
2шт type="radio"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

правильно ли я понимаю (что мне нужно сделать):

- мне нужно добавить id в каждый input
- и как-то через js прописать для каждой input action
- по нажатию отправляем на сервер и запись в куки и тд.

и не хотелось бы светить тут form+action

и как это сделать (как-то через js прописать для каждой input action). всем заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите чтобы переключения между режимами происходили мгновенно, тогда без js никак, думаю попробовать сделать через [livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/). Если без js то я бы передавал какую-то переменную в контроллер, например:

```
$displayType = $request->get('displayType', 'brick');
return  view("page.$displayType", [
        'models' => $models,
])
```